# Entering UK before visa expiry

Tags: visas, uk

My UK visa expires on June 22nd ... Can I enter the UK before that day and stay even if my visa expires?? I will have a return ticket to show

Comment: Are you asking if you can stay in the UK after your visa expires?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't stay after your visa expires - and if you show your return ticket with a date after your visa expiry, you can pretty much guarantee they won't let you in. Your visa is the document that states your permission to be in a country. You can expect to be looked poorly upon by border/immigration authorities if you are known to remain in countries without permission.

Comment: Just a comment: you shouldn't say "a" country, because while this may be true for the UK, it is not true for ALL countries (i.e. the US)